# How can I process this JSON in Python?

Tags: python

I'm trying to process the JSON below. I'm trying to specifically pull the data associated with one of the 'symbol' points.  Let's say I wanted to retreive the 'ask' for the 'localbtcARS' symbol. How can i do that in Python?

```
[
   {
      "volume":3.610000000000,
      "latest_trade":1379188723,
      "bid":1000.000000000000,
      "high":970.430000000000,
      "currency":"ARS",
      "currency_volume":3503.252300000000,
      "ask":774.310000000000,
      "close":970.430000000000,
      "avg":970.43,
      "symbol":"localbtcARS",
      "low":970.430000000000
   },
   {
      "volume":0,
      "latest_trade":1349296271,
      "bid":null,
      "high":null,
      "currency":"AUD",
      "currency_volume":0,
      "ask":null,
      "close":14.000000000000,
      "avg":null,
      "symbol":"bitmarketAUD",
      "low":null
   }
]
```

Comment: What have you tried? Googling for `python json` will give you all the answers you need.

Answer (score 3):

This is where the [`json`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html) module comes in handy:

```
import json
res = """the_list_of_dictionaries_posted_above_"""
mylist = json.loads(res)
for d in mylist:
    if d.get('symbol') == 'localbtcARS':
        print d.get('ask')
```